# gaps in employment history

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple employment history database, I store the entry id, user id, their job, start and end date.  There may be some overlapping entries.  I need to establish that in a given period there are no breaks of a given timeframe.

So user_id 1 have a work history like so

```
Marketing - 01/01/2013 to 19/05/2013
Sales - 01/01/2011 to 01/05/2012
Admin - 01/01/2010 to 31/12/2010
```

I actually store the dates as unix timestamp.  In a three year history user_id 1 has a break of over 6 months between their sales job and their marketing job.  How can I flag this to them so they can provide an entry for this period.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is harder than it seems, because you can have overlaps in employment history.  In fact, you can have one period of employment entirely "inside" another, or overlapping on either end.

What you are looking for is an EndDate that has a gap to a start date *and* isn't in another period of employment.  So, let's use a correlated subquery to get the next start date after the end date, as in:

```
     select t.*,
             (select StartDate
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.StartDate > t.EndDate
              order by StartDate desc
              limit 1
             ) nextStartDate
      from t
```

Now, the question is:  is the period from  covered by another period.  For this, I'll use a complicated `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select StartDate
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.StartDate > t.EndDate
              order by StartDate desc
              limit 1
             ) nextStartDate
      from t
     ) t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.StartDate <= t.EndDate and
                        t2.EndDate >= t.nextStartDate
                 ) and
      (t.EndDate is null or t.EndDate > now())
```

Depending on how you are handling the overlaps, you might want to allow a few days of lag between the dates.

This should return all records in your table where there are gaps.  In your example data, this would return record today (2013-05-19).  The "Sales" record has a gap afterwards until the "Marketing" position.  The "Marketing" will be returned in the future, because it will then have ended in the past.

It is actually possible that one gap will result in multiple records being returned.  This can happen when there are overlaps, which I will explain with just numbers:  (0, 10), (5, 12), (15, 20).  The gap starting at 12/13 will affect both records.  If this is an issue, then the query can be fixed, although my first thought on how to fix it makes the query even more complicated.

Presumably, you will also be filtering on the userid, which you can put in the outermost `where` clause.

Comment: Am I to assume by the error in SQL being thrown by the second code that this is the 'flag'?

Comment: @Dave . . . No, this should be returning all the records for your table where there is a gap afterwards.  The code had `t2.nextStartDate`, which should have been `t2.StartDate`.  I also added a check to filter out records that are currently active.

Comment: Cool, so the zero line result flags the error and I can send my user back to fill their details in?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking for something like this:

```
<?php
    $time_allowed = '1 month';

    $person = [
        [
            1305819929, // 19-05-11
            1337442341  // 19-05-12
        ],

        [
            1337442341, // 19-05-12
            1345933614  // 26-08-12
        ],

            // almost 4 month gap here - this will result in flagged() getting triggered

        [
            1355935614, // 19-12-12
            1368978787  // 19-05-13
        ]
    ];

    $time_allowed = strtotime('now') - strtotime("-{$time_allowed}");

    foreach($person as $key => $job)
    {
        if( ! isset($person[$key + 1]))
        {
            if($job[1] !== 'current' && (strtotime('now') - $job[1]) > $time_allowed)
            {
                flagged();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(($person[$key + 1][0] - $job[1]) > $time_allowed)
            {
                flagged();
            }
        }
    }

    function flagged()
    {
        // user flagged
    }
```

Obviously `$person` will be grabbed from the database. Script should be quite self-explanatory,

Comment: I thought that Dave only required the user to be flagged if he/she was off work for 6 months. I'll up date my post in a second.

Comment: i think it should be 99 to 100% mysql. you are 100% php

Comment: It works, though. I've never really looked into having 100% MySQL on something like this @DrewPierce

Comment: this is a classic case of something that should be done entirely by the database engine but a programmer that wants to loop thru with  terribly slow php code. yikes. what if there are 70 million rows ?

Comment: My script benchmarked: `Average: 0.00043180675506592 secs over 10000 iterations` this includes declaring the arrays and the foreach loop. Thats less than a millisecond and you're saying it's slow? EDIT: Actually, you've just edited your comment, and I don't think one person will have 70 million jobs in a small timespace... @DrewPierce - I think you've miss-read the OP.

Comment: no the point is that this is never solved in php. i am addressing this problem and those like it. your only tool is php. no one serious would solve problems this way. i have tables with over 300 million rows. i guess i would need to hire a different programmer for tables above 1000 rows ... is my point :>

Comment: There's nothing wrong with solving a problem in PHP. No one serious would solve problems like this? Seriously? It's much more simple in PHP than it is in MySQL. Why would you do all 70 million rows all at once? Why not just ask the user on login for example, that way you don't have a MySQL script running for hours and instead take less than a millisecond. @DrewPierce